# reset back to zero if value found ar

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have got an formula on excel whereby it calculate and add all the "**s**" from a range however is there anyway also to minus same value calculated if "**ar**" found within the same range

below it is the formula that counts all the "s" and add the result in to cell number B6

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(C3:C49978)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3:C49978,"s","")))
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @JvdV sorry but would you kindly be able to write me the formula

Comment: Original formula for counting "s"s in a range - this way didn't occur to me in first instance (not sure it would've).  I like it.

Comment: any feedback RE the solutions two of us have proivded?  what was it you were looking for in the end ?

Comment: given your commentary re: alternate interpretations of your Q - what would be good is if you provided clear examples / sample data with expected output (e.g. Excel screenshots, showing row and column labels + function bar)... ta

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(C3:C49978)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3:C49978,"s","")))*(LEN(C3:C49978)=(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3:C49978,"ar","")))))`
Using the same kind of logic you used I added a condition where the only from values that do not contain `"ar"` the occurance of `s` is counted otherwise it's ignored.

Comment: I see what you mean. Both can be true. I love your thoroughness though.

Comment: It's a curse of OC I tell you! ☺  fyi - the word that makes me question is "*also*" in OP's Q - makes me think that it's not meant to be one or the other - but 'union' if you know what I mean.  Certainly ambiguous - even if it turns out to be union I found two possible cases as you've seen.  Anyways- onto the next one - Merry Xmas/hols!

Comment: Hi Sorry for late reply. i have tested all your suggestion it does not seems to work when i put "ar". i basically would like to minus the count of "s" if there is "ar" in the range cells

Comment: Sorry what i meant is that if ranges between "B11:AF33" counts all of the "s" and if also "ar" within the same ranges then the count of all the "s" will need reset back to 0

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gYkKCW3yJpPm5YhxSw?e=eVpwIn)/screenshot(s) refer:

Dealing with ambiguity RE:

- Case 1: Counting all occurrences' of both 's' and 'ar'
- Case 2: Counting # 's' and subtracting count of 'ar'

**Case 1**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(2*LEN(C3:C50)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3:C50,"ar","."))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3:C50,"s","")))
```

[image: Case 1 = (C): total count]

**Case 2**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3:C50,"ar","."))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3:C50,"s","")))
```

[image: Case 2: = (D): count 's' less count 'ar']

**Notes**

• Suspect you're after case 1 - interested to know, but you have both cases anyway

• Assumes case-sensitive (so 'S' and 'AR' excluded from calcs.  To illustrate minor amendment to your function to count 'S' and/or 's' could modify as follows♣ :

```
=LET(x_,LOWER(C2:C50),SUMPRODUCT(LEN(x_)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(x_,"s",""))))
```

[image: Case insensitive variant of given function (A, count 's &/or S')]

Just for fun - an overcomplex variant of this (not recommended, hardly 'parsimonious' as is your function♣):

```
=SUM(1*(LOWER(LET(x_,TEXTJOIN("",1,C3:C9),FILTERXML("<x><y>"&MID(x_,SEQUENCE(LEN(x_),1,1,1),1)&"</y></x>","//y")))="s"))
```

[image: Over-complex alternative - case: insensitive count 's' &/or 'S']

♣ requires Office 365 compatible version of Excel

Comment: Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Sorry for late reply @JB-007 i have tried all the suggestion however no luck so far

Comment: i was wondering if there is any way around with the VBA code to do same results

Comment: Hi @Harin - did you try the linked workbook that provides the very same info I've supplied above but in an actual workbook so that you can see the functions working (or are you struggling with modification / tailoring to specfics of your workbook? If so, VB code would be even more cumbersome to tailor.  Give the file a go or elaborate RE what issues you encounter when attempting to replicate functions above pls